# Как указать Source из переменной wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Я создаю привязку в пути картинки, но мне выдает ошибку "Не найдет контекст данных для привязки MyPic"
XAML:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="600,108,0,0" Height="150" Click="Button_Click_CSGO">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Image x:Name="csgo" Source="{Binding MyPic}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

CS:

```
class MyViewModel
{
    public string MyPic
    {
        get { return "http://www.clipartkid.com/images/817/pic-of-german-flag-clipart-best-VkuN37-clipart.jpeg"; }
    }
}
```

Все облазил, но не понимаю почему не работает

Comment: А вы саму VM в DataContext указывали?

Comment: А что такое VM?

Comment: ViewModel :)...

Comment: Нет, и как это сделать?

Comment: В WPF (да и, по сути, как и везде), привязки работают так: 1. Вы делаете некий класс, в котором создаете нужные **публичные свойства**, к которым и будет идти привязка (в MVVM подходе это зовется `ViewModel`); 2. Вы задаете окну/контролу источник данных (`DataContext`), которым будет ссылатся на ранее созданный класс (`this.DataContext = new MySuperClass();`); 3. В XAML разметке нужному контролу задается привязка к нужному свойству (`<... SomeProperty = "{Binding Value}">`).  Собственно, у вас выше спрашивают, вы задали `DataContext`, который указывает на ваш класс `MyViewModel`?

Comment: Спасибо, пофиксил - заработало.